# Mathematica quickie: About making cells Input cells by default

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm going through some lecture notes, [*Fundamentals of Mathematica Programming*](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5216/) (see the .nb file there). I'd like to be able to do the exercises right there in the notebook; but for some reason I can't figure out how to make the default cell an Input cell. In other words, when I'm clicking in that notebook to create a new cell--in the exercises--the cell is by default a text cell. I'd like for it to be an Input cell so that I don't have to manually change it each time. Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default cell style of a vanilla Mathematica install should already be "**Input**". It sounds like you perhaps are using an edited default stylesheet or have changed the preferences.

For recent versions (6.0+), go to **Preferences**, and under the **Evaluation** tab, make sure "**Style of newly typed cells**" is set to `"Input"`, and that the drop-down below it labeled "**Format type of new input cells**" is set to `"StandardForm"`.

For older versions, make sure **Cell → Default Input FormatType** in the menu is set to `StandardForm`. To check/change the default cell input type, open **Format → Option Inspector...** in the menu and navigate to **Cell Options → New Cell Defaults** and set **DefaultNewCellStyle** to `"Input"`.

You can set the scope of the Option Inspector to **global** or **notebook** in the dropdown at the top. The particular notebook you linked to has the default style set to `"Text"` which is the problem.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately I'm working with 5.2. I can't find anything similar to what you describe. That's too bad, because "Style of newly typed cells" would have been too easy! 


So, otherwise, yes, I've downloaded the .nb file from above link and it looks like an edited stylesheet, whose preferences have been changed to text all the way around.

If you have any other ideas, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful, I appreciate this. It did the trick. A million thanks!

Comment: I wish I could throw some points your way; but as it is, new user here. Thanks again.